# Data type gets converted from "qlonglong" to "int" when creating Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, sql, virtual-layer, integer

I have a source layer with ID column as `qlonglong`. When I execute a query in DB Manager the types seems correctly preserved.

The problem is that if I "Load as New Layer" the resulting Virtual Layer has `qlonglong` converted to `int`.

As a consequence I cannot use this ID field to join to other tables.

It seems a very basic problem, but I've spent more than two hours and cannot find any better workaround than Refactoring the resulting Virtual Layer. I would love some help fixing the root problem.

Here is a link to [example file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!At5zYGcaz9K02YIbYEow5U5sh8Zuuw?e=aYdSNU)

Here is the Virtual Layer dialog, trying the cast suggestion. But I think type conversion happens not on source read, but on layer write.
[image]

Comment: Which version are you using? I couldn't reproduce it using 3.10.7. You could try to add a cast in your query `select myID::bigint, geom from mytable;`

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I'm using 3.10.7LTS. Same happens in 3.14.

I've tried your cast - maybe I do not understand the correct sintax, as I get :  unrecognized token: ":"

Comment: I've updated my question with an image of the Virtual Layer create dialog, and with the cast syntax. Still, the resulting layer has the qlonglong changed to int.

Comment: Interesting. The same query from the DB manager works: the field is recognized as qlonglong

Comment: I don't say the field is not recognised. What I say is that the resulting Virtual Layer has int instead of qlonglong fields. Did you try creating a Virtual Layer and checking the data type in it?

Comment: Ok I see, the **same** tool can produce different results. If you directly add a new virtual layer or use the `virtual layer` section of the DB manager, the field type is changed to int. If on the other hand you select a database in the DB manager and write the query, the field will remains a qlonglong, but the resulting query layer is not a virtual layer